# UK Standard Visit Visa for On-site Interview

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

Hie everyone, I live in Malaysia and just had my work permit approved here (I am African). I recently graduated and have been invited for an on-site interview by a Software Engineering company in London.

The thing is I don’t have 6 months payslips yet, is this a cause for concern? I had been working as intern at another company (pending graduation) and my bank statements only show my internship salary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no strict rule about how much money or how many statements are needed, with more statements the decision-maker will be able to see more easily your financial status and pattern of income/expenditure. The rule of thumb is six statements over a period of six months and the six month period should end with the most recent statement prior to submitting the application.

First-time applicants, those without a travel history or with any kind of adverse Immigration history, etc. are best to submit the full 6 months’ worth.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: Prior to my application I was earning an equivalent of USD 250 each month for the last 6 months (which is present in my bank statements) at my full time job I will be earning an equivalent of USD 1500 per month, could this help my case?

Comment: @Mark20 You need to satisfy UKVI that you are a genuine visitor who has sufficient funds available for the trip and will leave the UK at the end of your planned visit (V4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). Having a full-time job helps prove the latter, but future earnings don't help prove you have enough funds right now.